# Is there a way to prevent highcharter map from automatically choosing points?

Tags: r, highcharts, maps, r-highcharter

I am trying to make to make a plot in highcharter that has the districts of my country as mappoints. My issue is that instead of highcharter displaying the information when my cursor is on a point, it automatically outputs the details of the nearest point even if my cursor is nowhere near the map (but is still within the frame displaying the map). Is there a way to resolve this?

Some details: nash_geo is a shape file (converted to geojson) of my country and centers_geojson is a dataframe (converted to geojson) containing the coordinates and names of the districts I am superimposing on the map.

```
highchart(type = "map") %>%
 hc_add_series(mapData = nash_geo, showInLegend = FALSE) %>%
 hc_add_series(data = centers_geojson, type = "mappoint",
               dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE),
               name = "District", tooltip = list(pointFormat = " 
 {point.properties.district}"))
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot test it because I don't have your data and your chart isn't displaying in my environment, but you are probably looking for a stickyTracking property: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/plotOptions.series.stickyTracking

Comment: Yes! It turns out that you are right. Would you happen to know if there is a way to make it so that the mappoints' stickyTracking only happens within a certain radius of the points?

Comment: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.snap ??

Comment: Yes! This is correct. Is there a way to implement this in R. When I add it to hc_tooltip like the following, it changes nothing: hc_tooltip(pointFormat = table, useHTML = TRUE, snap = 10/25). It does not work when I put snap = 10 either.

Comment: I did some searching and unfortunately not. Snap isn't working with scatter series, more info here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3618
Mappoint series inherits from scatter.